# How to automate java applet using fest java?

Tags: java, swing, applet, automation, fest

I spent almost entire day on finding the answer of this question. I came to know that I can do this using Fest. I tried to understand how to do it using fest, but unable to understand it. There are not much tutorial available on fest. So can anyone help me on this? I want to know following things :

1)There is a applet running on a appletviewer on my desktop. How my code will recognize the applet? (a simple code snippet with explanation will help a lot.)
2)There is a log in , password field and a login button in the applet. How my code will recognize the field, fill suitable values and click on on login button?

(I am just a part time coder, so not very good with programming. So little detail will help me a lot. Thanks in advance.)